# PHP inside HTML inside Javascript inside PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this inside a while loop...

```
echo 'var contentString = '<div id="content" >
                           <div id="bodyContent">
                           <p>' + $row[name]+ '</p> 
                           </p>
                           </div>
                           </div>';';
```

but am getting unexpected idenitfier=id

I am using this while loop to load markers from a database and add them to a google map.

```
<?php
mysql_data_seek($query, 0);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $lat2 = $row['lat'];
    $lon2 = $row['lng'];
    echo 'var icon = customIcons[ "' . $row['type'] . '"];';
    echo 'var miLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(' . $lat2 . ',' . $lon2 . ');';
    echo 'bounds.extend(miLatLng);';
    echo 'var url = "markerpage.php?id=" + id;';
    echo "
  var contentString = &quot;
    <div id='content'>
      <div id='bodyContent'>
        <p>" . $row['name'] . "</p>
      </div>
    </div>&quot;
";
    echo 'var marker = new google.maps.Marker({';
    echo 'position: miLatLng,';
    echo 'map: map,';
    echo 'icon: icon.icon,';
    echo 'url: url';
    echo '});';
}
?>
```

javascript....

This function opens an infowindow with the contentString content

```
 function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, contentString) {
                                infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                                    content: contentString,
                                    maxWidth: 100,
                                    maxHeight: 100
                                });
                                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
                                    infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
                                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                                });
                                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                                    infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
                                    infoWindow.close(map, marker);
                                });
                            }
```

Comment: Because you're not escaping the single quote before `<div`  you also don't need the `+` as you're not really concating in js

Comment: What is your goal?!?

Comment: Also, if this is in a while loop, you'll probably want to have dynamic variable names otherwise this most likely won't work as expected. Maybe explain what you're doing and we can help with a better solution

Comment: Hey, I am loading markers on to a map. I will post more code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Think your looking for something like this:

```
echo "var contentString = \"<div id=\"content\">
                            <div id=\"bodyContent\">
                                <p>" . $row['name'] . "</p> 
                            </div>
                       </div>\";";
```

Also maybe it's good that you read this:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: Maybe but it appears he wants the js variable to contain that, and not just echo it out

Comment: @ElefantPhace I don't see his goal of this code! If he wants to output a javascript assignment or what

Comment: Yeah unfortunately need the JS variable as its being used in javascript functions, and it would be considerably messier to use the PHP variable the those

Answer (score 0):

Just escape the single quotes used in Javascript

```
echo 'var contentString = \'<div id="content" >
                           <div id="bodyContent">
                           <p>' . $row['name'] . '</p>
                           </div>
                           </div>\';';
```

Comment: getting an illegal token on this... any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways that I've gone about using quotes within quotes in PHP.

Here your browser will interpret the " as a quotation, and will work with JavaScript:

```
echo "
  var contentString = &quot;
    <div id='content'>
      <div id='bodyContent'>
        <p>" . $row['name'] . "</p>
      </div>
    </div>&quot;
";
```

Or you can use `\"` to tell PHP to ignore the quotation.

```
echo "
  var contentString = \"
    <div id='content'>
      <div id='bodyContent'>
        <p>" . $row['name'] . "</p>
      </div>
    </div>\"
";
```